# SVN/GIT versions

Tags: svn, version-control

I start SVN/GIT project and add a file style.css with contents:

```
body {color:red;}
header{color:blue}
footer{color:green}
```

After that 2 developers start 2 different tasks:
The first dev should split the files in 3 different files(body, footer, header)

The second should add more styles to the footer.

```
footer ul {color:pink}
```

The first dev commits work and second one commits after him.
The footer.css is now:

```
footer{color:green}
footer ul {color:pink}
```

The work on 2nd dev is tested but not on the 1st developer.
So the 2nd should publish changes to the production server.
But there is no footer.css file there because the work on 1st dev is not published.
How to handle this without human intervention.
Can i do someting automatically.

Comment: This is not really much so a subversion issue as much as it is a tree conflict and a development process issue. Tree conflicts will typically happen when you move/rename/split files like this. It's not going to make sense to subversion because it's almost impossible to tell you're splitting and renaming files. In my opinion here's what should've happened: Developer 1 was tasked to split the files into 3 files, correct? Since this task is techincally a _blocker_ for developer 2, this task should've been completed first. Developer 2 can work on the footer as necessary (cont.)

Comment: until developer 1 has split the files into the three that will be worked on primarily. Then, when developer 1 pushes his changes, developer 2 can merge the production server changes into his working copy. Both developers should be working on _branches_ of this repository. Therefore, when they merge back into the trunk, they can verify what's intended to be in the repo.